# Firebase vs Backendless

Tags: sql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am looking for a backend storage to use in a website, but i don't know what use: Firebase (NoSql) or Backendless (Sql).

Can someone tell me the differences, advantages and disadvantages...?

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with Firebase Real-Time Database, and it has huge problem when you need to make non-primitive query. For example, if you need to search by each word in string, then you need to load all data to the Algolia, keep it sync, and pay a lot of money (1$ for each 1000 requests).

But if you don't need to query data, just put and get it by ID, then Firebase database is perfect.

I didn't use Firestore, but I thoughtfully read documentation, and it has a LOT of limitations in querying, and still has no 'LIKE' query, like in SQL.

Also, I thoughtfully read Backendless documentation, and it has full power of SQL.

So, choose your service according to what you need:

1. If you need complex queries, choose Backendless
2. If you don't need it, choose Firebase, bc it has nice free plan (Backendless hasn't free plan for production projects)